# Passing data in transitionFromViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm using transitionFromViewController to switch between two view controllers using a segmented control.

Here's my code:

```
    @IBAction func valueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    var newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]) as! UIViewController
    let oldController = childViewControllers.last as! UIViewController



    oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    addChildViewController(newController)
    newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame

    if viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex] == "first" {

        let vc = newController as! userProfileViewController
        vc.userToShow = self.userToShow

    }

    transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
        // nothing needed here




        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            oldController.removeFromParentViewController()

            newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    })

}
```

is it possible to pass data to the childViewControllers, from the Parent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
        newController.property = currentProperty
        //basically here is where you can pass the data. I used a property as an example. You know what you need to send :)
    }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
        oldController.removeFromParentViewController()
        newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
})
```

Comment: It doesn't let me do that, since newController is of type UIViewController, while the controller that must receive the data is of type userProfileViewController

Comment: I don't understand. You have to View Controllers, oldController and newController in your example. You just need to cast the newController as userProfileViewController

When you init it do

var newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]) as! UserProfileViewController

Comment: I've tried, but it's not working...the view controller is not receiving anything

Comment: Check at run time, by setting a breakpoint, if your newViewController is alive (different then nil), and which type of class it is. If it's nil, you're not instantiating it correctly. Anyway, this is the proper method to pass the data during transition.

Comment: I can see that the right view controller is loaded, but no data is passed.

Comment: Alright I managed it. I need to send the data before addChildViewController(newController)